# How to send meeting invite (calendar) in Bluemix Node-Red Application

Tags: calendar, ibm-cloud, node-red, invite

I have created a Node-RED application in my Bluemix account. It has a http GET request node through which I receive the request. I receive a list of email ids in that request and I send an email to all those Id's and return a success as a response. Also I want to send a calendar meeting invite request to those id's and I couldn't find any thing in Node-RED through which I can send the meeting invite request.

Comment: What technology are you looking at to use to send a meeting invite?   Assuming Bluemix was not part of the story, what format would you send the meeting invite and to where would you send it?

Comment: using Javascript to google calendar

Answer (score 1):

Node-RED can be augmented with additional nodes that either you write or have supplied to you.  Googling around, I found the following additional nodes related to Google services:

http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-google

Specifically, there appears to be a service called "Calendar out" that, when invoked, creates an entry in a Google calendar.

Based on this, it would appear that my best/current recommendation is to create a Node-RED solution that leverages these additional flow nodes and push those to Bluemix for execution.

Comment: Thanks Kolban, I used this additional service in my app and provided the msg.payload with insert request object but it's throwing an error "failed to fetch calendar list: [object object]". Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: If we follow through on this node, we find that it's source is on Github.  In addition, there are open issues with it ... so what I suggest is that you visit the Github site here:

https://github.com/node-red/node-red-web-nodes/issues

Review the issues to see if your issue is amongst them and, if not, create a new issue describing your environment and as many details as possible.  The owners of that node will likely get back to you.

Comment: Got the code working, mostly the version of node-google service I was using was old one. Thanks a lot for guidance.